# Batch script for move files from one directory to another from list of text files (windows)

Tags: batch-file, move

I have two folder `1` and `2`. i save file list name in text `C:\a\filelist.txt`. file list contains files are available in folder `1`

which i want to move files from folder `1` to `2` using the file list from the text.

```
@echo off
move C:\a\1\"new.txt" C:\a\2
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) option, which uses the built-in [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) executable to check against the files listed in the text file:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%# In (
    'Dir /B /A:-D "C:\a\1" ^| "%__AppDir__%findStr.exe" /E /L /I /G:"C:\a\filelist.txt"'
) Do @Move /Y "C:\a\1\%%#" "C:\a\2"
```

Here's a shortened, single line Command Prompt, *([cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd))*, version:

```bat
For /F "EOL=|Delims=" %# In ('Dir /B/A-D "C:\a\1"^|FindStr /ELIG:"C:\a\filelist.txt"')Do @Move /Y "C:\a\1\%#" "C:\a\2"
```

This assumes that both your `%PATH%` and `%PATHEXT%` variables still hold their appropriate default values, or `findstr.exe` is located in the current directory.